# Is there a way to view traffic logs for Azure Storage for connections that got blocked by Firewall settings from Networking pane?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

Where can I find log within Azure Monitor/Log Analytics workspace that informs about some connection attempt (here from PowerBi service) that was dropped due to firewall settings? Can it be checked anywhere?

In Azure Storage Account I have enabled enabled all "Diagnostic settings" possible (account level, blob, queue, table etc.) and set "Send to Log Analytics workspace" for each of them. Then in "Networking" I've set "Public network access" to "Disabled" and triggered some published PowerBi report dataset refresh that uses Azure Table Storage within mentioned Azure Storage Account. Refresh fails with:

"There was an error when processing the data in the dataset.Hide details
Data source error:  The credentials provided for the AzureTables source are invalid. (Source at https://<account_name>.table.core.windows.net/.). The exception was raised by the IDataReader interface. Please review the error message and provider documentation for further information and corrective action. Table: <table_name>." error due to firewall settings. However in Log Analytics workspace I didn't find any logs of any rejected connection.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to view traffic logs for Azure Storage for connections that got blocked by Firewall settings from Networking pane?

To check the traffic logs for `Azure Storage` and see the connections blocked by **Firewall** settings in **Networking**, you can follow the steps below.

For testing, I have disabled **Public network access** in storage account, then when I try to access blob, the firewall is blocking the connection.

[image]

1. Enable diagnostic settings, skip this step if are already set up.
2. Go to **Insights > Failures.**

[image]

3. Here you can filter the log, if any traffic blocked from   networking for storage transactions.

[image]

5. **KQL** query to check the view traffic logs for azure storage for connections that got blocked by firewall.

```
let serviceValues = dynamic(['blob']);
let operationValues = dynamic(['*']);
let statusValues = dynamic(['AuthorizationFailure']);
StorageBlobLogs
| union StorageQueueLogs
| union StorageTableLogs
| union StorageFileLogs
| where StatusText != "Success"
| where "*" in ('blob') or ServiceType in ('blob')
| where "*" in ('*') or OperationName in ('*')
| where "*" in ('AuthorizationFailure') or StatusText in ('AuthorizationFailure')
| extend Service = ServiceType
| extend AuthType = AuthenticationType
| extend CallerIpAddress = split(CallerIpAddress, ":")[0]
| summarize ErrorCount = count()
    by
    Service,
    OperationName,
    StatusText,
    StatusCode,
    AuthType,
    tostring(CallerIpAddress),
    Uri
| sort by ErrorCount desc
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Hi @Venkat. Thank you for your input. In principle your answer is absolute correct. What is keep bothering thought me is **why firewall incidents (AuthorizationFailure (403) aka Firewall Deny) are logged for StorageBlobLogs but not for StorageTableLogs?**. Any ideas? Maybe it is not curently covered by Azure?